# Easy example of an infinite simple group with an embedding into a finitely presented group

Tags: gr.group-theory

I would like an easy example of an infinite simple group along with an embedding into a finitely presented group. I know that there are infinite simple finitely presented group such as Thompson’s group $V$ and I know that any group with solvable word problem embeds into a simple subgroup of a finitely presented group, but I am looking for an example of a more elementary nature.

Comment: One example is  Burger-Mozes's group in "Finitely presented simple groups and products of trees", https://ethz.ch/content/dam/ethz/special-interest/math/department/Research/Research_Groups/Burger/1997_Finitely_presented_simple_groups.pdf.

Comment: And there are many more examples, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_group#Infinite_simple_groups.

Comment: @Igor. Thanks but if possible I’m looking for something a bit more elementary. It is easy to say what the Burger-Mozes groups are but proving that they are fp and simple is not so easy.

Comment: That Burger-Mozes groups are finitely presented is somewhat immediate once constructed. But the construction, and the proof of simplicity are both subtle.

Comment: The group $A$ of alternating finitely supported permutations of an infinite countable set embeds into Houghton's group $H_3$. The latter is quite easy to construct, and that it is finitely generated and contains $A$ is easy, and that $A$ is simple is also easy. That $H_3$ is finitely presented is more technical with some combinatorial arguments.

Comment: So you're looking for a simple simple group?

Comment: @IanAgol I understand this is a joke (I often blame our glorious ancestors to deprive us from the informal word "simple" in group theory). But taking it literally, I understand that the OP also wants the finitely presented group and the embedding to be based on elementary arguments. Indeed the OP already mentioned the Boone-Higman fact, so that every countable computable simple group, e.g. $\mathrm{PSL}_2(\mathbf{Q})$ works (with a complicated embedding).

Comment: @IanAgol precisely the Houghton group $H_d$ is a extension of the finitary symmetric group by $\mathbf{Z}^{d-1}$, and is finitely presented for $d\ge 3$. Also this extension is non-split for $d\ge 3$. For $d=2$ this is the B.H. Neumann group of permutations of $\mathbf{Z}$ generated by $+1$ and the transposition $(0,1)$ (which is finitely generated and not finitely presented as you noticed).

Comment: @YCor You should add that as an answer, at least I will learn something. I thought the Thompson groups were simple, but I guess not simple enough.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think D. L. Johnson's article *[Embedding some recursively presented groups](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/groups-st-andrews-1997-in-bath/embedding-some-recursively-presented-groups/A5CF8D51C4641ECB739C7A8CBDC98531)* should answer your question. The abstract is:

> We seek to illustrate the Higman Embedding Theorem by finding actual embeddings
>   of various popular recursively presented groups in finitely presented ones,
>   and are successful in at least one case.

In particular, Section 3 contains a short and elementary proof of the fact that the group $S_\infty$ of bijections of $\mathbb{N}$ with finite supports (which contains the infinite simple group $A_\infty$ of alternating bijections) embeds into a finitely presented group. A presentation for such a group, simplified in Section 4, is
$$\langle a,b,x \mid a^2=1, (xaxa^{-1})^3=1, [x,a^2xa^{-2}]=1, x=[a,b], axa^{-1}=bxb^{-1} \rangle.$$
Actually, the group defined by the presentation coincides with Houghton's group $H_3$ already mentioned by Yves in the comments.

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks!

Comment: To have a complete proof of an embedding, one needs to check that $[x,a^nxa^{-n}]=1$ in this group for all $n\ge 2$.